# Can't receive custom Intents from AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I want my alarms (Android AlarmManager) to repeat every N seconds.

There are some classes that I use:

**AlarmReceiver** (receives alarm Intents and repeats them using AlarmHandler class);

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        AlarmHandler.repeatAlarm(context, intent);
        completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

**AlarmHandler** (sets, cancels and repeats the alarms);

```
public class AlarmHandler {
    public static void setAlarm(Context context, String intentName, int delay, long beginTime, long endTime) {

        if(endTime<beginTime) {
            return;
        }

        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(intentName);
        alarmIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
        alarmIntent.putExtra("Delay", delay);
        alarmIntent.putExtra("EndTime", endTime);
        PendingIntent pendingAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 0,
                alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null) {
            alarmService.cancel(pendingAlarmIntent);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            alarmService.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(android.app.AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    beginTime,
                    pendingAlarmIntent);
        }
        else {
            alarmService.setExact(android.app.AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    beginTime,
                    pendingAlarmIntent);
        }
    }

    public static void setAlarm(Context context, String intentName, int delay) {
        setAlarm(context, intentName, delay, System.currentTimeMillis()+delay, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    public static void repeatAlarm(Context context, Intent intent) {    
        PendingIntent pendingAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        if(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null) {
            alarmService.cancel(pendingAlarmIntent);
        }

        int intentDelay = intent.getIntExtra("Delay", 0);
        long intentEndTime = intent.getLongExtra("EndTime", Long.MAX_VALUE),
                alarmTime = System.currentTimeMillis()+intentDelay;

        if(intentDelay > 0 && alarmTime<intentEndTime) {    
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                alarmService.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        alarmTime, pendingAlarmIntent);
            }
            else {
                alarmService.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, pendingAlarmIntent);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void cancelAlarm(Context context, String intentName) {    
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(intentName);
        PendingIntent pendingAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager  = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingAlarmIntent);
        pendingAlarmIntent.cancel();
    }
}
```

**Some specific classes** to receive custom Intents (for example, *com.lukanin.testappjava2.BLUETOOTH_INTERVAL*) from Android AlarmManager;

```
public class fakeReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

My **Manifest** (AndroidManifest.xml) file looks like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".fakeReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.lukanin.testappjava2.BLUETOOTH_INTERVAL" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name=".Alarm.AlarmReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.lukanin.testappjava2.BLUETOOTH_INTERVAL" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

So what's about the problem? Firstly I set Android AlarmManager from Main Activity with:

```
AlarmHandler.setAlarm(context, "com.lukanin.testappjava2.BLUETOOTH_INTERVAL", 1000 * 30 * 1);
```

Logcat output:

```
10-14 14:35:00.924 32451-32451/com.lukanin.testappjava2 I/(ALARM): SETTING NEW ALARM
10-14 14:35:00.924 32451-32451/com.lukanin.testappjava2 I/(ALARM): INTENT NAME: com.lukanin.testappjava2.BLUETOOTH_INTERVAL
10-14 14:35:00.924 32451-32451/com.lukanin.testappjava2 I/(ALARM): DELAY: 30000
10-14 14:35:00.925 32451-32451/com.lukanin.testappjava2 I/(ALARM): BEGIN TIME: 1476444930924
10-14 14:35:00.925 32451-32451/com.lukanin.testappjava2 I/(ALARM): END TIME: 9223372036854775807
```

Then I receive my *com.lukanin.testappjava2.BLUETOOTH_INTERVAL* Intent just once with **fakeReceiver** and number of times with **AlarmReceiver**. What am I doing wrong? These receivers are totally identical!

Logcat output:

```
10-14 14:35:06.491 32451-32451/com.lukanin.testappjava2 I/(ALARM): ALARM RECEIVER
10-14 14:35:06.491 32451-32451/com.lukanin.testappjava2 I/(ALARM): REPEATING EXISTING ALARM
10-14 14:35:06.491 32451-32451/com.lukanin.testappjava2 I/(ALARM): INTENT NAME: com.lukanin.testappjava2.BLUETOOTH_INTERVAL
10-14 14:35:06.491 32451-32451/com.lukanin.testappjava2 I/(ALARM): CONTEXT: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@4432f21

10-14 14:35:25.694 32451-32451/com.lukanin.testappjava2 I/(ALARM): ALARM RECEIVER
10-14 14:35:25.694 32451-32451/com.lukanin.testappjava2 I/(ALARM): REPEATING EXISTING ALARM
10-14 14:35:25.694 32451-32451/com.lukanin.testappjava2 I/(ALARM): INTENT NAME: com.lukanin.testappjava2.GPS_INTERVAL
10-14 14:35:25.694 32451-32451/com.lukanin.testappjava2 I/(ALARM): CONTEXT: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@4432f21

10-14 14:35:30.932 32451-32451/com.lukanin.testappjava2 I/FAKE: FAKE RECEIVER

10-14 14:35:30.946 32451-32451/com.lukanin.testappjava2 I/(ALARM): ALARM RECEIVER
10-14 14:35:30.946 32451-32451/com.lukanin.testappjava2 I/(ALARM): REPEATING EXISTING ALARM
10-14 14:35:30.946 32451-32451/com.lukanin.testappjava2 I/(ALARM): INTENT NAME: com.lukanin.testappjava2.BLUETOOTH_INTERVAL
10-14 14:35:30.946 32451-32451/com.lukanin.testappjava2 I/(ALARM): CONTEXT: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@4432f21

10-14 14:35:55.712 32451-32451/com.lukanin.testappjava2 I/(ALARM): ALARM RECEIVER
10-14 14:35:55.712 32451-32451/com.lukanin.testappjava2 I/(ALARM): REPEATING EXISTING ALARM
10-14 14:35:55.712 32451-32451/com.lukanin.testappjava2 I/(ALARM): INTENT NAME: com.lukanin.testappjava2.GPS_INTERVAL
10-14 14:35:55.712 32451-32451/com.lukanin.testappjava2 I/(ALARM): CONTEXT: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@4432f21

10-14 14:36:00.975 32451-32451/com.lukanin.testappjava2 I/(ALARM): ALARM RECEIVER
10-14 14:36:00.975 32451-32451/com.lukanin.testappjava2 I/(ALARM): REPEATING EXISTING ALARM
10-14 14:36:00.975 32451-32451/com.lukanin.testappjava2 I/(ALARM): INTENT NAME: com.lukanin.testappjava2.BLUETOOTH_INTERVAL
10-14 14:36:00.975 32451-32451/com.lukanin.testappjava2 I/(ALARM): CONTEXT: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@4432f21
```

Comment: aren't u suppose to register fakereciver in ur manifest ??

Comment: Already did it. There are 2 receivers in my AndroidManifest.xml now.

Comment: Its working as u have coded. In onReceive of AlarmManager u r calling  AlarmHandler.repeatAlarm(context, intent); and in FakeReceiver u r not

Comment: But... **AlarmHandler.repeatAlarm** method creates PendingIntent with broadcast _com.lukanin.testappjava2.BLUETOOTH_INTERVAL_ Intent. Why doesn't my **fakeReceiver** able to receive it? It's broadcast.

Comment: you may have to use ordered broadcast receiver read it here http://codetheory.in/android-broadcast-receivers/  under Normal and Ordered Broadcasts section

Comment: leave a comment if that works for u

Comment: Thx so much! With ur this examples I finally found a solution. It's not really related to Ordered Broadcasts... Now I just hold the actual action name (e.g. _com.lukanin.testappjava2.BLUETOOTH_INTERVAL_) in the Intent extra and then forward Intent from **AlarmReceiver** to any other receivers (with **context.sendBroadcast()**).